# Play a certain audio track when clicked

Tags: php, jquery, html

All the songs have a `.song` class but it plays the first song on the playlist. It's basically the play button for the whole playlist. I've play around with this for awhile and I can't seem to get it right. It might be the simplest thing too. I have the song populate with php depending on the album. I want people to be able to click a certain song and that song plays.

example: http://mixtapemonkey.com/mixtape?m=637

Also if you know how to toggle between the play and stop button, that would be nice to throw in there too. Thanks!

```
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    i=0;

    nowPlaying = document.getElementsByClassName('playsong');
    nowPlaying[i].load();

    $('.play').on('click', function() {
        nowPlaying[i].play();
        callMeta();
    });

    $('.song').on('click', function() {
        nowPlaying[i].play();
        callMeta();
    });

    $('.pause').on('click', function() {
        nowPlaying[i].pause();
        callMeta();
    });

    $('.next').on('click', function() {
        $.each($('audio.playsong'), function(){
            this.pause();
        });
        ++i;
        nowPlaying[i].load();
        nowPlaying[i].play();
        callMeta();

    })

    function callMeta(){
        var trackTitle = $(nowPlaying[i]).attr('data-songtitle');
        $('.songtitle').html(trackTitle);

        var trackArtist = $(nowPlaying[i]).attr('data-songartist');
        $('.songartist').html(trackArtist);

    }

})
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to target the audio element inside each `.song`, now you're always targeting the first one.
To toggle, check if the audio is `paused`, and `play()` or `pause()` accordingly :

```
$('.song').on('click', function() {
    var audio = $('.playsong', this).get(0);

    if (audio.paused) {
         audio.play();
    }else{
         audio.pause()
    }
    callMeta();
});
```

**EDIT:**

with a few changes, I'm guessing something like this would work :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var audios = $('.playsong');
    var audio  = audios.get(0);

    audio.load();

    $('.play').on('click', function() {
        callMeta(audio);
    });

    $('.song').on('click', function() {
        audio = $('.playsong', this).get(0);
        callMeta(audio);
    });

    $('.pause').on('click', function() {
        audio.pause();
    });

    $('.next').on('click', function() {
        var i = audios.index(audio);
        audio = $(audios).get(i+1);
        callMeta(audio);
    });

    function callMeta(elem){
        audios.each(function(i,el) {
            if (!el.paused) {
                el.pause();
                el.currentTime = 0;
            }
        });
        elem.load();
        elem.play();
        $(elem).on('ended', function() {
            $('.next').trigger('click');
        });
        $('.songtitle').html($(elem).attr('data-songtitle'));
        $('.songartist').html( $(elem).attr('data-songartist') );
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank, this worked for the most part. The callMeta() didn't seem to work. The song displays the title for first song listed still but plays the song I clicked. Also if I click another song, it doesn't switches, it just play two songs at the same time.

Comment: Yes, you have to pause any other songs playing, and your `callmMeta` function has the same issue, it's using `nowPlaying[i]` which will always be the first song.

Comment: So how do I get my callMeta() to use the audio variable? Should I set all my code to use the audio variable?

Comment: oh, that's much better. The next button isn't working for some reason, I tried getting `i` to add +1 in a lot different ways but it's not working? also how easy would it be to let songs play when they're done. The song just ends and I have to click the next one.

Comment: @MarkSerrano - did some changes, try it now

Comment: It works. great job! Unfortunately it turns out it's not working with my updated jQuery. 

it only works for
`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>`

not my new:
`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

I'm gonna try to figure out what's the problem, thanks for helping me this far. Appreciate so much!

Comment: Open the console and check for errors, I can't really see anything in the code that shouldn't work with the newest version of jQ ?

Comment: It's running all my other jQ stuff just fine. I don't know if something is clashing or what. I looked in my editor and no bugs are popping up. 

you can look in my source code if you want? 
[link](view-source:http://mixtapemonkey.com/)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33724/discussion-between-mark-serrano-and-adeneo)

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarity - you say the songs have class "song", yet your code says "playsong". A typo, perhaps?

The first song always plays because you always play `nowPlaying[i]`, and `i=0` - which *only* changes when `$('.next').on('click', function(){})` is called! You need a way to either change `i` when a song is clicked, or make the HTML more "modular" (I use this loosely) around each song.

Example HTML:

```
<audio id="coolSong1">
    <!-- Sources -->
</audio>
<!-- I'm not sure what you're using as play, pause, next buttons, so I'll use buttons -->
<input type="button" class="play" name="coolSong1" value="play" />
<input type="button" class="pause" name="coolSong1" value="pause" />
<input type="button" class="next" name="coolSong1" value="next" />
```

Corresponding script:

```
$(".play").click(function(event) {
    document.getElementById(event.target.name).play();
});
$(".pause").click(function(event) {
document.getElementById(event.target.name).pause();
});
```